# Deploying nlp algorithm with spaCy on pythonanywhere

Tags: pip, conda, spacy, pythonanywhere

I have a text classification algorithm that runs on spaCy and sklearn. I'm trying to deploy it via flask and pythonanywhere. The problem is I can't get my environments to match up.

I can install spaCy on my local machine, but only through Conda. I can install spaCy on pythonanywhere, but only through pip. The problem is that whith the conda install I get two packages:

```
mkl-fft==1.0.6
mkl-random==1.0.1
```

that apparently the pip installation doesn't use. So what I think is happening is that when I deploy the Conda trained algorithm to the pythonanywhere environment where spaCy was pip installed, it doesn't work. the two packages cannot be installed on pythonanywhere.

How do I solve this problem?
Do I need to find a host that can do conda installs? If so which ones can accommodate this?
Can I solve this by pip installing spaCy on my own machine and retraining the algorithm?

Not sure if any of this is clear, I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that spaCy, numpy and scipy were configured to use MKL. In order to solve this I did create a new virtual environment and then did a conda install of the nomkl module. From there I just reinstalled the packages and they were no longer MKL configured and I was able to get consistent remote and local environments.

Comment: Hint: [you can accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Not for another day I can't unfortunately

Comment: No problem, you're not obliged. :-)

Comment: Oh I'm pretty proud that I was able to find this solution so I most definitely will :)